# excel vba upload file to ftp server

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I am using the following script in excel to try and upload a text file to my server. For some reason my script is failing.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? all the login details are correct and my ftp server address is correct. Not sure why it won't work?

I have the script placed in a module and have the module assigned to a active x button control

```
'Open the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetOpen _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetOpenA" _
       (ByVal sAgent As String, _
        ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
        ByVal sProxyName As String, _
        ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

'Connect to the network
 Private Declare Function InternetConnect _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetConnectA" _
       (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
        ByVal sServerName As String, _
        ByVal nServerPort As Integer, _
        ByVal sUsername As String, _
        ByVal sPassword As String, _
        ByVal lService As Long, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long, _
        ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

'Get a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpGetFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpGetFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
        ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, _
        ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Send a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpPutFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpPutFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Close the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     (ByVal hInet As Long) As Integer

Sub UploadFTP()

  Dim hostFile As String
  Dim INet As Long
  Dim INetConn As Long
  Dim Password As String
  Dim RetVal As Long
  Dim ServerName As String
  Dim Success As Long
  Dim UserName As String

  Const ASCII_TRANSFER = 1
  Const BINARY_TRANSFER = 2

    ServerName = "***"
    UserName = "****"
    Password = "***"
    localFile = "P:\TEST.txt"
    hostFile = "/public_html/TEST.txt"

      RetVal = False
      INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1&, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)
        If INet > 0 Then
          INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, ServerName, 0&, UserName, Password, 1&, 0&, 0&)
            If INetConn > 0 Then
              Success = FtpPutFile(INetConn, localFile, hostFile, BINARY_TRANSFER, 0&)
              RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
            End If
         RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INet)
        End If

      If Success <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Upload process completed")
      Else
        MsgBox "FTP File Error!"
      End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using WinSCP; I've found it to be more reliable. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35644297/5472502) for an example.

Comment: In the instructions that define functions, I get the error ``The code of this Project must be updated to be used on 64 bits systems. Revise and update Declare instructions, then, mark them with PtrSafe attribute``